# problem with bitmap not displaying image after a text

Tags: android

i am trying to show an image directly under a text which i had retrieved from a file in the sdcard but only the text is showing but not the image,

have been trying several methods but non of it is workable

below is my code to display them

```
//Find the directory for the SD Card using the API
    //*Don't* hardcode "/sdcard"
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    //Get the text file
    File file = new File(sdcard,"file.txt");

    //Read text from file
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        //You'll need to add proper error handling here
    }

    //Find the view by its id
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

    //Set the text
    tv.setText(text);

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.icon);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 130, 10, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't see anywhere in your code where you are trying to set the bitmap. Whatever, what about using compounds drawables?

```
//Find the view by its id
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

//Set the text
tv.setText(text);

tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null,
   null, null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
```

Comment: hey thanks for the prompt reply, however what if i needed the image to be right below each text for example HELLO i need 1 image right below each text and not at the bottom of the screen

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
```

you are creating a Canvas to draw *into* the bitmap. That's not the way to do what you want. Instead, just tell the text view to use your icon as the top drawable:

```
tv.setText(text);
tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, R.drawable.icon);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i tried the tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds i was looking at placing the image just below the letters i am calling and not below the screen

Comment: reason being is that for example HELLO i would like to add 2 image directly below each letter